# Multiple regulatory changes at the cutoff

Tags: econometrics

Consider a running variable $a$, and a cutoff $a_0$.

There are two regulatory variables, $x$ and $z$. Both variables jump around $a_0$, in the sense of fuzzy regression discontinuity design (RDD) setting.

Can I disentangle the effects of two regulatory changes on $y$ by using $1(a>a_0)$ as an instrument variable for $x$ and $z$?

Comment: Do you have other variables in your regression? Or is it just y=x+z with coefficients, and you want to instrument x and z with a? Is that right?

Comment: David: Thank you for your reply. I have other covariates, but I am also curious why it matters.

Comment: Cause you need to have at least as many instruments as regressors, and that condition cannot be satisfied as your regression is now. You could possibly run two separate regressions, one for each IV, with the other covariates included. Is there a particular reason why you want to include both endogenous regressors in one single regression?

Comment: David: What I want to examine is the effect of regulatory changes in $x$ on $y$, but I am worried whether my result is driven by another regulatory changes in $z$.

Comment: I see. Maybe someone else has a good idea for this, but imo if your data is really marked by the introduction of two policies around the same fuzzy cut-off, then there is no way to disentangle the effects of these policies, unless you have a clear a priori economic argument about what these effects should be. Unless you could find a different instrument than the running variable for one of both.

Comment: @David Thank you so much for your kind explanation! Now I get your point clearly! Then, I am considering to exploit the fact that cutoffs for x and z is different at period 1 (say a0 and a1 respectively), while they are same at period 2 (a0). Do you think it could make another problem?